# Is this ajax post correct?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to post to my CakePHP action an array of variables so I can edit them. The array is built from the ids of the table rows.  Here is the javascript code that is in my index.ctp file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.edit_selected').click(function()
{
    var selected = new Array();
    alert('Edit Selected Has Been Clicked');
    $("#[id*=LocalClocks]").each(function()
    {
        if(false != $(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id').replace('LocalClocks', ''));
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/localhost/LocalClocks/editSelected/",
            data: JSON.stringify(selected),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){ alert(data); alert('Edit Success'); }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

What I am doing here is grabbing all the ids that start with `'LocalClocks'`, then I am trimming off the `'LocalClock'` string so I end up with only numbers, then I add that id number into the selected array.  I want to post this array to my `editSelected()` function.

I am not familiar at all with posting data, so I have a few questions.  Is the current code I have correct so far?
For my `editSelected()` function, does it need a parameter for the array I am trying to pass it, or does the posted data get put into `$this->request->data`?

Here is my `editSelected` action:

```
public function editSelected()
{
    $this->set('isEditSelValid', false);
    $this->set('editSelValidationErrors', false);
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $localClocksEntries = $this->LocalClock->find('all');
        foreach($localClocksEntries as $LocalClock)
        {
            $this->LocalClock->id = $LocalClock['LocalClock']['id'];
            $this->LocalClock->save($this->request->data);
            $this->set('isEditSelValid', true);
            $this->set('editSelValidationErrors', false);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I am trying to post data is because I need to be able to get the ids of the rows I want to edit.  I have check boxes in each row which the javascript above is able to get and put into an array.  I need to be able to loop that array and save the user input to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server-side code accepts JSON you will need to add `contentType: "application/json"` to the literal object being passed to the `ajax` method.  Right now it is being sent with the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Other than that your code looks sound.

`datatType` is used for the return data and `contentType` is how your request data is being passed.

Comment: How can I tell if my server side code accepts JSON? Is there built in functionality? If not then my code does not support JSON because I did not write any code to do so.

Comment: I am not familiar with CakePHP so I am not sure how it binds the request data.  The reason I answered the way I did is because it appears you are sending JSON, which I assume you would be doing if you explicitly need to send JSON and if you are, you need to specify the contentType.  If I were you I would try adding the contentType above first.  If that does not work, remove it and format `selected` as a literal object e.g. `{"Key" : "Value"}`.

Comment: I added the contentType to the ajax call right above the datatype.  It still didn't work (I think).  If the ajax is correct then I can work on getting that information in my action.  Thanks for the help with the ajax stuff. I cant do the literal object because the array is being filled in dynamically.